# SEF URL Broken Image Links When Fetching API Results

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, custom-component, sef, restful-api

Using Joomla 3.9.8

I'm using the [fetch() api](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-the-fetch-api) in order to retrieve some data from a remote API. When I have the api results I'm displaying them in html elements.

The API returns various values, one of these is `url`, I need to insert this `url` into an image `src`. This is normally pretty easy, but i've noticed that when I try this in Joomla the image `src` is rewritten and prefixed with my site name. This is causing **broken images**.

In order to insert the code i'm using [Sourcerer](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/sourcerer) and a custom html module.

I've created a stripped back example to demonstrate the issue. For this example I will use the [random user api](https://randomuser.me), but the logic is the same with any api.

The code I am inserting into the custom html module using sourcerer is;

```
<script>
fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      var url = data.results[0].picture.large;
      console.log(url);
      // displays https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/47.jpg
      console.log('<img src=" '+url+' ">');
      // displays <img src="/example.com/ https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/47.jpg " >
})
</script>
```

I am logging the `url` variable to the console, and the issue is clear. The image `src` is being prefixed with my domain name.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whq2tcgy/) containing the exact same code, different results.

I'm almost certain it's an issue with Joomla SEF URLs because when I disable the plugin > System - SEF **everything works as expected**.

I've read an [article explaining](https://www.itoctopus.com/images-not-appearing-on-your-joomla-website) the issue and some possible troubleshooting steps like re-arranging the plugin order, but nothin appears to work.

Hopefully someone can help as i've been stuck on this for quite a while now.

Comment: Can you try doing this without Sourcerer and see if you get the same results?

Comment: I've just tried adding this code snippet on my own site **without** Sourcerer (SEF enabled) and it work's perfectly fine.

Comment: @Lodder would you believe.. I had a space in my code here `'<img src=" '+url+' ">'` (between the double and single quotes). I obviously fixed it when asking the question and forgot about it! What a waste of a morning :/ Thanks for your help

Comment: Haha how unfortunate. Feel free to write this as an answer and mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: Hmm, why doesn't JSE have a close reason for Off-topic: Typo questions like this one?

Comment: @Lodder thanks for the sympathy haha! Also thanks for pointing me in the direction of using fetch(), it's great! I'll add an answer now

Comment: @mickmackusa I don't think this question is necessarily off topic? When I add an answer it will potentially help another person facing the same (trivial) issue. Also, I can see a close reason `off-topic because...`

Comment: After reading [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356342/294340), I think the goal in retaining this page as a valuable resource for researchers should be to ensure that the question title and body isolate the root cause and make finding this page from a google search very easy.  Think for a moment what search terms you would use if you encountered this issue -- those buzzwords/keywords should be in the title and the body.  Separately, when volunteers cannot reproduce the issue as described in their own environment, the question is Unclear / confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I made this far too difficult for myself.

The answer is that I had a **space** in my code, right after the opening `img src="` this was causing the Joomla SEF plugin to prefix my domain URL in the space.

Original code;

```
console.log('<img src=" '+url+' ">');
```

Working code;

```
console.log('<img src="'+url+'">');
```

Hope this saves someone else a few hours work.

Comment: I'm still very interested as to how a space could result in the `/example.com/` being prepended to the `src` value. I wonder if it's Sourcerer trying to be clever.